# Nuget Powershell Rename content file

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I am looking to rename a file that I have loaded via a nuget package:

I know I can get the file like this:

```
$f = $project.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_.ProjectItems } | where { $_.Name -eq "MyFile.cs.custom" }
```

I also know I can delete that file like this:

```
$f.Delete()
```

I am just looking for the syntax to rename that file.  I have tried just doing:

```
$project.ProjectItems | ForEach { $_.ProjectItems } | Where { $_.Name -eq "MyFile.cs.custom" } | Foreach {Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.FileNames -replace "\.custom", "")}
```

And that didn't work

The install.ps1 file in it's entirety is:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

#save the project file first - this commits the changes made by nuget before this     script runs.
$project.Save()

$project.ProjectItems | ForEach { $_.ProjectItems } | Where { $_.Name -eq "MyFile.cs.custom" } | Foreach {Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.FileNames -replace "\.custom", "")}

$project.Save()
```

I ended up working around this by just changing the project startup object of the csproj file to be a class that didn't already exist in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will be usefull for somebody, at least it works for me. In this piece of code I'm looking for the folder "FolderConfig" in root folder (for example C:\projects\SomeProject\FolderConfig\" and then rename files. You can remove filter by folder "FolderConfig" and search these files in all project.

```
$project.ProjectItems | where { $_.Name -eq "FolderConfig" } |
ForEach { $_.ProjectItems } |  where { $_.Name -eq "Test.config"} |
ForEach { $_.Name = "NewTest.config" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that ProjectItems are of type FileInfo so try this:

```
$project.ProjectItems | ForEach { $_.ProjectItems } | 
    Where { $_.Name -eq "MyFile.cs.custom" } |  
    Foreach {Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.FileNames -replace "\.custom", "")}
```

I think you're going to need to find a property on the item that corresponds to the fullname (path) of the file (to use as the Path for rename-item), unless you can guarantee that PowerShell is cd'd into the file's containing directory.

Also, watch out that `-replace` uses regex meta-characters.

Note that `FileNames` may return multiple file names in a single string.

Comment: Put `-verbose` on the rename-item cmdlet so you can see what it is attempting to rename from and to.

Comment: I suspect you need more than the `Name` property.  Is there a `Fullname` or `Path` property on the item?

Comment: Change the last Foreach to `Get-Member` and see what properties this DTE object has on it i.e. Where {...} | Get-Member

Comment: According to this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.filenames.aspx - the property is called `FileNames`.

Comment: That still didn't work correctly as part of the install.ps1 file

Comment: Did you try -verbose? If so, what did it output?

Comment: Wondering if anyone has any news on this? Did anyone ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

our install.ps1 file should look something like this.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$file1 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("test.exe")
$file2 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("test.config")

// set 'Copy To Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer'
$copyToOutput1 = $file1.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput1.Value = 2

$copyToOutput2 = $file2.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput2.Value = 2
```